# importMesh of undefined from undefined version: undefined, exporter version: undefinedimportMesh has failed JSON parse

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am getting this error(importMesh of undefined from undefined version: undefined, exporter version: undefinedimportMesh has failed JSON parse) while trying to load the .babylon file in BabylonJS application.

Comment: Could you please add more information. Example file’s. What steps did you do. What are you trying to achieve. And why you think the solution is inside blender?

Comment: @J.Bakker- Here is he code where i am trying to import the .babylon file
(JSON)BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("Man", "./assets/manbab/", "man.babylon", scene, function (newMeshes, particleSystems, skeletons) { });  where i am getting the error as   :   importMesh of undefined from undefined version: undefined, exporter version: undefinedimportMesh has failed JSON parse